# select columns that don't contain a pattern in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I would like to select all the columns that don't contain the pattern "acc".

I writed this piece of code

```
select (
select COLUMN_NAME  from  information_schema.columns 
where table_name='output_bba'
    and column_name not like 'acc%') 
    from ifrs17.output_bba
```

but I receive this error message :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Does anyone can help me on this issue?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in the above, the subquery seems to be all you need here; why do you have the outer `SELECT` and `FROM`?

Comment: Seems you are trying to select from the Column name(s) that you want to get. You cannot do this directly. Read the column names into a variable. Then generate a string for the dynamic SQL and then execute it.

Comment: Also, what about the error don't you understand? It's very explicit on what the problem is; your subquery is returning multiple values (in the case rows), and that isn't allow in the context it's used in (as an expression).

Comment: The error clearly tells you: your subquery returns more that one row. You can use only scalar subquery in `SELECT` list (subquery that returns single value, this is because of 1NF nature of SQL). But this is not needed, the subquery answers your question by itself

Comment: It is strange because I made a check and i don't have duplicates in the column names.

Comment: In SQL data and objects (identifiers) are of different nature, they cannot be mixed. Just paste direct column names. Some DBMSes allow you to select columns by pattern, but in SQL Server it is not possible without dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Nassim you should take some SQL tutorials where you'll learn how to write SQL statements. The task you try to solve (dynamic column names) works differently because SQL designed in different way.

Comment: @astentx thanks for the info. Indeed I am working on SQL Server. do you have an idea how to write this dynamic query?

Comment: @Nassim Why do you need this dynamic SQL? It is bad practice to have dynamic SQL all around, it is very hard to maintain. So not to give bad advices: you'd better describe the task you want to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to select from columns that are being obtained dynamically. Try this:

```
Declare @Cols varchar(max)
Select @Cols=Stuff((Select ','+COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns Where table_name='output_bba' and column_name not like 'acc%' For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

Declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
Set @SQL='Select '+@Cols+' From ifrs17.output_bba';

Execute sp_executesql @SQL;
```